# What is a "space-charge", in the context of photodetector non-linearities?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I'm going back and reading all these papers from a few decades ago regarding detector nonlinearities, and they talk a lot about space-charges and the space-charge field, but not one paper I've found after 2 hours of searching gives a real complete picture of what the space charge is and how exactly it contributes to non-linearities in the detector's response.

Anyone have a good idea, a review article, a book or pdf to point me towards?

Comment: It is the charge of the photoelectrons in the vacuum, which at higher electron densities affects potentials and fields.

Comment: In the vacuum? You mean in the semi-conductor?

Or do you mean when we ignore the semiconductor and just treat it as a bunch of excitons in a uniform field?

Comment: Why not in vacuum? Your question doesn't specify whether you're interested in semiconductor or vacuum tube detectors. Links or at least citations to the papers you're talking about would also help us understand the context of your question.

Comment: As pointed out, there are space charge effects in most detectors. Your photon generates charge, that charge has to be transported somewhere to register as a blip in the system. If you generate a lot of charge, that transport will not be the same as for a single electron. That is space charge effects.

Comment: @ConnorSkehan You referred to papers from several decades ago, that is why I guessed that you asked about vacuum detectors, like photomultiplier tubes etc. And that is where the term originates. In semiconductors it is different, because there are both electrons and holes, with different and anisotropic velocities.